# Inserting lines into IPython history

Tags: ipython

I'm using IPython for some lectures and it would be very convenient if at different points during the lecture if I could add a few lines (say 3 or 4) to the input history.  That way I could recall them with a couple of up-arrow keystrokes.

I don't want to clear the history or start the session with a new history.  I need to push a few lines at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by pushing a few lines to the history?  Wouldn't pre-typing them and hitting `Ctrl-R` for searching back work?

Comment: Not really.  What I already have is a way to drive my powerpoint presentation with the text and graphics from ipython.  However, for each slide, I'd like to have a few preselected commands, each of which I could execute with the push of a button.  I can't have all of the commands pre-loaded, as I'd spend too much time trying to get to the proper one.